# Relative positioning without z-index causes overlapping

Tags: css, z-index

I created two sibling divs and applied negative margin on the last one, but when I added `position: relative` to the first one, it overlapped its next sibling:

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.box-1 {
  position: relative;
  background: orange;
}

.box-2 {
  margin-top: -50px;
  background: yellowgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="box box-1">box-1</div>
<div class="box box-2">box-2</div>
```

However, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) says that

> positioned (absolutely or relatively) **with a z-index value other than "auto"** will create a new stacking context.

So I guess it isn't the stacking context that causes overlapping, any idea about how this happens?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Standard blocks in the normal flow, without any positioning property, are always rendered before positioned elements, and appear below them, even if they come later in the HTML hierarchy.

Example being

```css
.absolute {
    position: absolute;
    background:purple;
    left: 80px;
}

.relative {
    position: relative;
    left:50px;
    background:yellow;
    top:-50px;
}

div {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border: 1px dashed #999966;
    background:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="absolute">absolute</div>
<div>normal</div>
<div class="relative">relative</div>
<div>normal</div>
```

Something cool about relative though, is that it's still considered to be in it's original location, even if it's been moved if you're using `left, right, top, bottom`. If you use margins to position the element the boundaries of the container are also moved with it. This can be [seen using the same example](http://jsfiddle.net/mtov878w/1/) above but changing the relative position to use margining. [Reference to relative positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Relative_positioning)

Answer (score 1):

Non-positioned elements are always rendered **before** explicitly positioned elements. This means that by applying `position: relative` to 'box-1', it is rendered **after** 'box-2' and so appears on top of it.

Comment: Why rendering order will affect stacking order? Is there any post talking about this?

Comment: Because no z-index is specified (which affect stacking order), the only thing that dictates their position is rendering order. Using Sean's link, there's a quote which says - "Standard blocks (DIV #5) in the normal flow, without any positioning property, are always rendered before positioned elements, and appear below them, even if they come later in the HTML hierarchy. "

Comment: The quote is from the yellow 'Notes' box in the following page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/Stacking_without_z-index

Answer (score 0):

The overlapping is caused by `margin-top: -50px;` in your CSS

Comment: I don't think negative margin will cause overlapping, check this: http://jsbin.com/himodi/2/edit?html,css,output

Comment: @Dolphin_Wood is referring to the fact that div2 is 2nd in the Dom, yet still underneath div1.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a decent explanation:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/Stacking_without_z-index

> Standard blocks in the normal flow, without any positioning property, are always rendered before positioned elements, and appear below them, even if they come later in the HTML hierarchy.

Comment: Granted this shows why it happens, at least provide some context here instead of linking away